# How to disable UI components based on value in selectOneMenu

Tags: jsf

With the value I get from my combobox, I need to unlock 1 of the elements (inputText) and block the other:e.g

if selecOnMenu value is "A" then inputText with idA is unlocked and the other's blocked

xhtml code:

```
 <h:form prependId="false">
            <p:selectOneMenu id="enviado"  value="#{combo.valor}">  
                <f:ajax event="change" execute="enviado" render="saida" />
                <f:selectItem itemValue="#{null}" itemLabel="Selecione um item"  />
                <f:selectItems value="#{combo.disponiveis}" />
                    </p:selectOneMenu>  

                        <br></br>
            <h:outputText id="saida" value="opção: #{combo.valor}" />

        <div>
            <p> Opção A -- Falta implementar</p>        
                <p:inputText id="idA" value="Insira texto aqui" disabled="??????" />                
                </div>

        <div>
            <p>Opção B -- Flta implementar</p>      
                <p:inputText id="idB" value="Insira texto aqui" disabled="??????" />        
                </div>

        </h:form>

    </h:body>
    </html>
```

UPDATE:

I make it work now using on disable = "#{combo.valor != 'idB'}"

now only need to make the ajax work with it

UPDATE 2:

Well, when using `<p:inputText>` didn't work, but with `<h:inputText>` works fine.

UPDATE 3:

I just need to use the right ajax element, i was using jsf just trying to re-render a primefaces element, with the primeFaces ajax worked

Thank you

Comment: `disabled="#{combo.valor == yourID}"` in inputText and rendering of idA and idB in `selectOneMenu`

Comment: I tried disabled "#{comob.valor == idA}" but didn't work

Comment: Do you re-render inputText(s) when selectOneMenu is changed?

Comment: Yes, I did a update on the question